# Let $x_1 = 2$, $x_{n+1}=2+\frac{1}{x_{n}}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Does the sequence converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fixed-point-iteration

Let $x_1 = 2$, $x_{n+1}=2+\dfrac{1}{x_{n}}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Does the sequence converge or diverge?

How can I solve this question using Monotone Convergence Theorem or any other better method? I can't think of a way to show it as monotone increasing or decreasing?

Comment: You might want to start by drawing the graph of the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=2+\frac1x$ on $x>0$, just to understand what is going on.

Comment: Moreover: before going for monotonicity, try to compute the first few terms to get a sense of what may happen. (They are *not* monotone.)

Comment: It oscillates and converges to $1+\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Interestingly, WolframAlpha obtains an explicit solution to this recurrence relation: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Bn+%2B+1%5D+%3D%3D+2+%2B+1%2Fx%5Bn%5D,+x%5B1%5D+%3D%3D+2. The convergence to $1+\sqrt{2}$ is then obvious. But having to know the explicit solution seems like overkill!

Comment: You can find several posts about this sequence on this site. For example, by [searching for $x_{n+1}=2+\dfrac{1}{x_{n}}$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3D2%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx_%7Bn%7D%7D%24&p=1) in Approach0.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Let $r$ be the positive root of the equation $x=2+\frac{1}{x}$ (which is $1+\sqrt{2}$).

$|x_{n+1}-r|=|(2+\frac{1}{x_n})-(2+\frac{1}{r})|=\frac{|x_n-r|}{r|x_n|}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_{1}=2$, $q_{1}=1$.

\begin{align*}
  p_{n+1} &= 2p_{n}+q_{n} \\
  q_{n+1} &= p_{n} \\
  p_{n} & > q_{n} \\
  p_{n} &\ge 2^{n} \\
  q_{n} &\ge 2^{n-1}
\end{align*}

Also,
\begin{align*}
  p_{1}^{2}-2p_{1}q_{1}-q_{1}^{2} &= -1 \\
  p_{n+1}^{2}-2p_{n+1}q_{n+1}-q_{n+1}^{2}
  &= -(p_{n}^{2}-2p_{n}q_{n}-q_{n}^{2}) \\
  &= (-1)^{n+1} \\
  \frac{p_{n+1}^{2}}{q_{n+1}^{2}}-\frac{2p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}-1
  &= \frac{q_{n}^{2}}{p_{n}^{2}}+\frac{2q_{n}}{p_{n}}-1 \\
  &= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{p_{n+1}^{2}} \\
  x_{n} &= \frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}} \\
  x_{n+1}-x_{n} &= \frac{2p_{n}+q_{n}}{p_{n}}-\frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}} \\
  &= \frac{2p_{n}q_{n}+q_{n}^{2}-p_{n}^2}{p_{n}q_{n}} \\
  &= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{p_{n}q_{n}} \\
  &= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{q_{n}q_{n+1}} \\
\end{align*}

Now
\begin{align*}
  L &= \lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n} \\
  0 &= L^2-2L-1 \\
  L &= \sqrt{2}+1  \tag{reject $1-\sqrt{2}$}
\end{align*}

> **Further notes:**
>
> Solving the recurrence relations explicitly, we have
>   $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
>   p_{n} \\ q_{n}
> \end{pmatrix}=
> \begin{pmatrix}
>   \dfrac{(1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{2} \\[3pt]
>   \dfrac{(1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}-(1-\sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{2}}
> \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint For any $c>1$, $f(x) = 2 + \frac1x$ is contractive in $[c,\infty)$ (why?). Apply [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) to the recurrence $x_{n+1} = f(x_n), x_1 = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

First, show that $$x_1 + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} |x_{k+1}-x_k|$$ converges (This is simple, since we can show by induction that $x_n\ge 2$, for all $n$ and $|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|\le\frac{|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|}{4}$). Then, from the fact that "absolute convergence implies convergence" and also
$$
x_N = x_1 + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} x_{k+1}-x_k
$$
we have the result.